# looking for a very accurate and sensitive accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer

For a research type project, we are looking for a very accurate and sensitive accelerometer (preferably 6-axis). The average range of the acceleration that we need to record is about 0.0003g (g=gravitational acceleration=9.81m/s2). The minimum sampling rate of measurements should be about 250Hz. We have no electronic engineering background and so we are looking for a readily available module that can be simply installed and connected to a data processor (eg Raspberry pi or a similar one) for recording data. we need to use these sensors for one of our mechanical engineering projects. 
Your comments and help are appreciated.
Thanks.
M.

Comment: You may find [Robotics Stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) more useful for this question.  Copy your question there, then delete it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking **recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them** are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)